# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject throws exception on uint64, returns null object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, win-universal-app

I am working with the newly-released Halo API to make a Universal Windows App that will display some CSR data for players over time. The data comes back from the API in JSON format, but one of the endpoints is returning a ulong/uint64 that is tripping up Json.net's default deserializer. I was getting an exception about an integer being "too large or small for an int64," and looking at the JSON, I was indeed getting a number that was larger than an int64. However, since I am not interested in that particular part of the data, I was hoping to just skip the exception and keep the rest of the data. I am deserializing into a dynamic object because I am hoping to keep and use a lot of the data. However, it looks like skipping the exception by marking it as handled does not work since JsonConvert.DeserializeObject returns a null (the custom error handler does get called).

Here is an example that is using a snippet of the JSON that is causing the issue:

```
    private async void RetrievePlaylistData()
    {
        string fakeJson = "{\"Data4\": 9414319071796913811}";

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.Error = delegate (object sender, ErrorEventArgs args)
        { 
            var currentError = args.ErrorContext.Error.Message;
            args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        };

        dynamic playlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fakeJson, settings);
    }
```

Does anyone have recommendations for how to handle the exception better or parse the data correctly so that I can get a proper dynamic object back? Or is a data contract my best option here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The first two thirds of your question seem irrelevant, to be honest - and the final part doesn't give the same error. Once I'd converted it into a short but complete console app, it gave an error of "JsonToken EndObject is not valid for closing JsonType Array. Path 'MetaCommendationDeltas', line 1, position 376." I would fix up that JSON, but it feels to me like it would be *much* better if you'd just reduce the amount of JSON to a [mcve].

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What version of the JSON library are you using? It's serializing the value into `BigInteger` for me.

Comment: I am using version 7.0.1, which appears to be the latest version of the library. If it makes any difference, I added it to my project in Visual Studio using a Nuget package

Comment: @SlyCaptainFlint Could you try running this: `string fakeJson = "9414319071796913811"; BigInteger res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BigInteger>(fakeJson);`

Comment: Hm, unfortunately, I'm seeing the same exception.
JSON integer 9414319071796913811 is too large or small for an Int64

Comment: Interesting bit of info - I just created a super basic C# console application:
            `string fakeJson = "9414319071796913811";`
            `dynamic res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fakeJson);`        

This runs just fine without any errors. I suspect this failure might be related to the universal windows app environment, but I'm not sure what could possibly be causing it.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: Also, do you know exactly which Json.NET DLL you are referencing?

Comment: My app is using the .NET Core library, which is what universal windows apps use (I am not sure if this is dependent on a particular version of .NET or how I could check that. For Json.NET, I am using version 7.0.1, but this is the version number on the nuget package, which I'm not sure maps directly to the DLL version. Seems to match the latest version listed on the json.net website, though

Comment: I don't have a development environment for Universal WIndows Apps to hand.  Does your environment have [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?  The docs say *Universal Windows Platform: Available since 4.5* so it looks like you should have it.